# SpringBoot external config not picked up when started outside directory with application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ansible

I have a service that needs to run as a jar on a server.  Because the components and dependencies to the jar use spring & spring boot, this jar includes spring and has to be configured with an application.yml file.  I am using ansible to deploy the system, but I cannot get ansible to successful start the service because on startup, the service is not picking up the application.yml file.  After some debugging, I figured out that if I start the service in a different directory than the application.yml, it fails then too.

Setup that works:

1. Build the tar with gradle using springBoot task. `./gradlew build`
2. Copy the resulting tar to the remote server and uncompress.  Lets call the uncompresses directory `deploy_dir`
3. Copy a production application.yml to deploy_dir
4. Copy the following script (start.sh) to deploy_dir:

   `#!/bin/bash
   nohup /home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/bin/project -Dspring.config.location=/home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/application.yml 1>/home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/out.log 2>&1 &`
5. ssh into machince and run ./start.sh

Those steps work, but if I copy start.sh to the home directory, and run it from there, the application.yml does not get picked up and I get the following errors.

`2017-10-25 14:24:58.730  INFO 31582 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2017-10-25 14:24:59.599  INFO 31582 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c78541e8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)`

**It is important that I get start.sh working from the home directory (or a directory different from the one application.yml is in) because I strongly believe that getting it to work there, will allow the jar to be started with ansible with the correct config.**

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
compile('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'2.8.0'

runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')

}

jar {
baseName = 'project'
version =  '0.0.1'
manifest {
    attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile,
            'Main-Class': 'com.MainClass'
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set your config location as a directory. Also put the "file:" prefix before.

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:/home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have found works is to add a line to start.sh to cd to the directory where the script works.  This works for ansible and running start.sh script manually on the server.  I don't really know why this works and it seems shady, but it is what works.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/deploy_dir
nohup /home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/bin/project -Dspring.config.location=/home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/application.yml 1>/home/ubuntu/deploy_dir/out.log 2>&1 &
```